# Why use `stash@{n}`?

Tags: git

`git stash apply stash@{n}` contains a number of hard to type characters and repeats some information.

Is there a reason for repeating the `stash` and using the at-sign and braces instead of something easier to type, like `git stash apply n`, for instance?

Comment: I'd like to understand the motivation behind this notation as opposed to one that is more immediately obvious to myself, an outsider who is not very familiar with git. Is there a better way to word the question?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because, despite being initially worded as "why *this exact* syntax?" which is technically a subjective opinion poll only the designers can answer, the real question of why it has such an odd, non-obvious syntax is a fair question with an objectively correct answer (as shown below).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually a simple instance of a much more general syntax for specifying symbolic references (basically, all the things in `.git/refs`). From the current [git documentation on revisions](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions):

> `<refname>@\{<date>\}, e.g. master@{yesterday}, HEAD@\{5 minutes ago\}`
>
> A ref followed by the suffix @ with a date specification enclosed in a brace pair (e.g. {yesterday}, {1 month 2 weeks 3 days 1 hour 1 second ago} or {1979-02-26 18:30:00}) specifies the value of the ref at a prior point in time. This suffix may only be used immediately following a ref name and the ref must have an existing log (`$GIT_DIR/logs/<ref>`). Note that this looks up the state of your local ref at a given time; e.g., what was in your local master branch last week. If you want to look at commits made during certain times, see --since and --until.
>
> `<refname>@\{<n>\}, e.g. master@{1}`
>
> A ref followed by the suffix @ with an ordinal specification enclosed in a brace pair (e.g. {1}, {15}) specifies the n-th prior value of that ref. For example master@{1} is the immediate prior value of master while master@{5} is the 5th prior value of master. This suffix may only be used immediately following a ref name and the ref must have an existing log (`$GIT_DIR/logs/<refname>`).
>
> `@\{<n>\}, e.g. @{1}`
>
> You can use the @ construct with an empty ref part to get at a reflog entry of the current branch. For example, if you are on branch blabla then @{1} means the same as blabla@{1}.
>
> `@\{-<n>\}, e.g. @\{-1\}`
>
> The construct `@\{-<n>\}` means the `<n>th` branch/commit checked out before the current one.
>
> `<branchname>@{upstream}, e.g. master@{upstream}, @{u}`
>
> The suffix @{upstream} to a branchname (short form @{u}) refers to the branch that the branch specified by branchname is set to build on top of (configured with `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge`). A missing branchname defaults to the current one.

It's very understandable why the `stash@{0}` syntax would seem unnecessarily ornate if you've only seen it used in the context of stash refs.